# Building packages: command which yields 'amd64' (like uname)

Tags: debian, compiling, make, architecture

Suppose I have a makefile that builds my package, and I only want the package to build if the package file is not present:

```
package: foo_0.0.0_amd64.deb
  cd foo-0.0.0 && debuild -uc -us
```

So I am new to the debian build process, but I am anticipating that I'll either find a way to build for different architectures, or I'll be on a different architecture natively and that file name will change.  So, I set it as a variable:

```
major=0
minor=0
update=0
release=amd64
package: foo_${major}.${minor}.${update}_${release}.deb
```

I have a machine where `uname -r` yields `#.##.#-#-amd64`. What is the bulletproof way to fetch that `amd64` in unix/linux?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On a Debian-based system, the bullet-proof way of determining the architecture, as appropriate for use in a package’s file name, is

```
dpkg --print-architecture
```

Note that architecture-independent packages use `all` there, and you’d have to know that in advance.